# Dynamically adding javascript to <head>

Tags: php, javascript, dom, dynamic, include

I am using a function "loadScript" to insert an external .js if the browser detects it is online.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadScript()
{
    if (navigator.onLine == true)
    {
        var src =  "js/getdata.js";
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = src;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }
}
</script>
```

It all works fine except that the final script appears as...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/getdata.js">
function getData() // get MySQL data from db
{
<?php
$dbopen = 0; // database flag
$con = mysql_connect("website.co.uk","guest","password");
mysql_select_db("DB", $con);
if (!$con)
{die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
else
{$dbopen = 1;}
?>
```

etc...

And the Firebug console tells me the function getData is not defined and the content

```
<?php
```

is a syntax error...

I would like to get the script into the head and have it defined as a usable function within the DOM.

I would appreciate any thoughts you may have.

GitaarLAB asked for the whole code, so here it is.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadScript()
{
if (navigator.onLine == true)
{
    var src =  "js/getdata.js";
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
loadScript();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/getdata.js">
function getData()
{
<?php
$hhgopen = 0;
$con = mysql_connect("website.co.uk","guest","password");
mysql_select_db("ThisDB", $con);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles", $con);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$hhgopen = 1;
}
?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't mix inline and included javascript. Include js/getdata.js in one script tag and then the PHP output in another script tag

Comment: your script should be defined in pair tag <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getdata.js"></script>

Comment: You say: *'...works fine except that the final script appears as... CODE'*. This *can NOT* be happening. Executing `loadScript` in a browser can never ever render the resulting CODE you have posted: it should render `<script src="js/getdata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Proof in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAQCY/).    Something else must be wrong (*very strange*, since it is a mystery where `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/getdata.js">` *without* the closing script-tag comes from), so we need more code (especially surrounding the parts you already posted).

Comment: GitaarLAB - This is exactly what is happening. The code is rendered exactly as I have shown in the head. I just need to know why the resulting script is "not defined" when the DOM attempts to access it. This is a small dummy file and there is very little else to show. I can post the whole thing if you want.

Comment: I have used your html and code is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/justnajm/27NXr/

Comment: See my solution below. The issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the script to be generated by PHP, you need to put it in a PHP file. Rename the file to `js/getdata.js.php` and update the `src` accordingly.

Another option would be to configure the web server to parse all `.js` files as PHP, but it's unlikely you actually want to do that.

Comment: I don't need the script to be generated by PHP. The PHP is within the function that is being added. It is the content of the getData.js file. All I need is for the function getData to be defined in the DOM and thus usable when I call it. I can see why there may have been some confusion. I have posted the whole code above (as gitaarLAB requested).

Comment: I think the problem is you are requesting a js file which contain php code in it, remember that js is not parsed by php. If you want to request js then this solution is OK

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not set to process .js files as php. So it just sends out that file as a plain text (like it would do with the regular javascript file).

Try to rename that file to have .php extension.

Answer (score 0):

To run PHP in an external JS file you have usually to do the following:

1. Rename getdata.js to getdata.js.php
2. Add a special header output to the getdata.js.php to identify it as javascript

   header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Quick note: Anything can be contained inside a PHP document whether its raw text, HTML, JavaScript or simply PHP code. Your telling the browser to link a js document. The PHP code contained within this file will not execute because there's nothing telling the server to parse over it with the PHP engine.

Try to rename your file to "getdata.php" or "getdata.js.php" and update the source attribute of your script tag. You should be good to go after that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Thanks to Mark Parnell and W3Geek who gave me the script.js.php extension clue. The element to load the script should not be a function.

Details: It now runs as a script in the head, loads the function if it is online, then waits for window.onload before trying to call the new function.

So now, if the app is online, it gets data from PHP. If the app is offline it gets data from cache and localStorage.

IOS no longer parses the PHP within the getData function which causes an error when the app is offline.

Hope this is of some use.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.onLine == true)
{
var src =  "js/getdata.js.php";
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = src;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){getData();};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```